# How to move old file to another folder

Tags: linux, shell

in my folder I have file which suffix is date when this file was created for example:
file.log2012-08-21, file.log2012-08-20 ... Now how I can move file which is older then 2012-08-20 ? I know how I can do this day by day: `mv file.log2012-08-19 /old/` but I dont know when to stop ... is there some parameter in command mv to do this easier ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ls -l | awk '{print $NF}' | awk 'substr($0, length($0)-9, length($0)) < "2012-08-20" {system("mv "$0" /old/")}'`

This will move all the files older than "2012-08-20" to the folder "/old". Likewise, you can change the "2012-08-20" to specify particular date you want. Note this assumes that the file suffix is a date stamp, but the prefix can be any name.

If you just need to move files older than a certain days, then I think rkyser's answer is better for that.

Comment: hm and where do you specify name of file ? there can be file.log2012-08-19 or file1.log2012-08-19 file2.log2012-08-19 but I want to move just file.log* ...

Comment: @hudi It just extracts all files with a date suffix. You only change the "2012-08-20" to whatever date you want.

Comment: ah ok but when I add name of file after ls:  ls -l file then it should works right ?

Comment: That's right. If you use `ls -l whatever`. It'll work as long as the names end with a date suffix. For example, `ls -l log.file*` would work the same.

Answer (score 13):

You could use `find` with the `-mtime` parameter. This assumes that the file suffix as mentioned above matches the datestamp on the file.

- `-mtime +1` means find files more than 1 day old
- `-mtime -1` means find files less than 1 day old
- `-mtime 1` means find files 1 day old

Example (updated):

```
find . -type f -mtime +1 -name "file.log*" -exec mv {} /old/ \;
```

or if you only want to `find` in the current directory only add `-maxdepth 1` (otherwise, it will search recursively):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +1 -name "file.log*" -exec mv {} /old/ \;
```

Comment: hm and where do you specify name of file ? there can be file.log2012-08-19 or file1.log2012-08-19 file2.log2012-08-19 but I want to move just file.log* ...

Comment: backslash at the end of "/old/" is important... without it only last file is moved to file "/old".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your log files are not modified after their last line is written:

```
find . ! -newer file.log2012-08-20 | xargs -r -IX mv X /old/
```

Note: with this command file.log2012-08-20 would be moved as well. If you don't want it, use the previous file:

```
find . ! -newer file.log2012-08-19 | xargs -r -IX mv X /old/
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write a small script for this. If all you files are in a specific naming convention like `file.log2012-08-21`, then something like this would do the work.

```
since=$(date --date="2012-08-20" +%s)
for file in `ls -1 --color=none`
do
    date=$(date --date="${file#file.log}" +%s)
    [ $date -lt $since ] && mv -v $file /old/
done
```

Before you really do this, it is a good idea to change the mv command to echo to see if the files about to be moved is right.