# Searching files older than a specific time and move them into a specific folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can someone help me in fixing a script for searching files in a specific folder which is given as argument, and move them into another folder? 
I have tried looping into a while loop but with no success and I don't understand what am I doing wrong. I am new to to linux scripting and trying to understand it.

```
StructuraFoldere=$1
shift
VechimeFis=$2
shift
Dirmutat=$3
shift
cout=1
echo

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
if [ -g $# ]
then -ls $#
fi
shift
echo find /"$#" -maxdepth 1 -mtime +"$VechimeFis" -type f -exec mv "{}" "$Dirmutat" \; 
shift
cout=$[cout+1]
shift
done
```

Comment: Check out the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/q/12055712/2088135 (the top-voted one is better than the accepted one).

Comment: Not what I need. Not the query is the issue but the while loop, I don't understand how to use it corrct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one-liner can find the files in the directory passed as the first argument `source directory`, which is older than the second argument `age` and move the filtered files to the third argument `destination directory`

```
#!/bin/bash
find /"$1" -maxdepth 1 -mtime +"$2" -type f -exec mv "{}" "$3" \;
```

Comment: But if in that folder there is a hierarchy of folders it will not search in?

Comment: It will mv the files and folders to the destination folder specified. If your requirement is more broad please specify.

Comment: The requirement is to search in a hierarchy of folders for all the files older than a specific date time and move them into a second folder, Maybe I wasn't to specific in the description. I am sorry

Comment: Updated the answer based on the clarification

Comment: sorry for that :-D but the requirement was made more clearer in the comments added\

Comment: Ok thank you for the query.  I have updated the script in the description, but it still doesn't return anything, it seems to be something wrong with the while loop.

Comment: Thank you both :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer the most general part of your question, "I am new to to linux scripting and trying to understand it."  I'm doing this because it looks to me like you are at the very beginning; the main thing that tells me this is that you are using **both** `$1`, `$2`, etc **and** `shift`.

Compare these two scripts:

First script:

```
FIRST=$1
shift
SECOND=$2
shift
THIRD=$3
shift

echo $FIRST
echo $SECOND
echo $THIRD
```

If I run this with `./scriptname.sh 1 2 3`, I get the output:

```
1
3
    # a blank line
```

Second script:

```
FIRST=$1
SECOND=$2
THIRD=$3

echo $FIRST
echo $SECOND
echo $THIRD
```

If I run this with `./scriptname.sh 1 2 3`, I get the output:

```
1
2
3
```

In other words, the `shift` is not necessary, and actually interfering.  You only need to use `shift` when you do something like this:

```
FIRST=$1
shift
SECOND=$1
shift
THIRD=$1
shift
```

... or, more commonly, reading `$1` repeatedly inside of a loop.

Here is a really, really good resource for learning shell scripting:

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html

This will help you from the very beginning, and I still find it to be a very valuable resource even after 25+ years of shell scripting.

While this does not answer your specific question, I sense that you need a more solid footing on basics that are preliminary to your stated goal. 
 I feel strongly that this will help you accomplish your broader goal -- to learn shell scripting.  If you read and work carefully through the above Bash Beginners's Guide, you will soon see a way (or several ways!) to write the file searching / moving script you asked about specifically.

HTH.

Answer (score -1):

So, you'll probably want to use the find command.

```
my_directory=${1}
m_time = ${2}
for file in `find ${my_directory} -type f -mtime +${m_time}`; do mv -v ${file} /move/here; done
```

This will only find files in $1 dir that are older than $2 days and move them.
(This is not tested but it gives you an idea on what to do)